# How do I make my a little script run on page load?

Tags: jquery, onload

Here is my little script

```
<script> $("#header").append($("#live"))

  ); </script>
```

What is the jQuery to get this to run on page load, preferably before the page is rendered?

Comment: "On page load" and "before the page is rendered" is an oxymoron.

Comment: When you have decided when you want it loaded, we can help you.

Comment: Sorry about that I'm not good at this javascript stuff as having just been an html coder and now trying my hand at jscript, so in fact i would like it to run asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#header").append($("#live").html());
});
```

your line will result in syntax error

Comment: The code i'm using infact us as below using a click to enact the jscript.                                                     <script type="text/javascript">
$('.switcher').click(function(){
    
    // this is the bit you're interested in
    $('#live').appendTo('#header');

});
$('.switcherReset').click(function(){
    
    // this is the bit you're interested in
    $('#live').appendTo('#header');

});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

To run on page load, use:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(window).load ( function () {
        $("#header").append ( $("#live") );
    } );
</script>
```

---

To run as soon as possible, use:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready ( function () {
        $("#header").append ( $("#live") );
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

"On page load" typically *means* "once the page is rendered".

So, I'll have to guess at what you mean:

- To run it as a first step, before the `body` starts to be rendered, just put your `script` as-is (albeit with the syntax error fixed) in the `head` tag. That's the earliest you can run Javascript.
- To defer it until the DOM has been loaded, do what @genesis showed you, with jQuery's on-load wrapper syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I'm unable to put code in head tag it will in fact be in the footer (o well) due to limited access to source that I have been given. So will wrap it as described and will just have to run after the DOM (page) has loaded.  Thanks very much for all the help.